# Can't compile when using archive/tar

Tags: go

I am trying to use `archive/tar` within my Golang project. However, when I compile it, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: /go-cache/10/1020ddd253c007d4f0bbed6c73d75297ac475bbc40d485e357efc1e7584bc24f-d(_go_.o): cannot use dynamic imports with -d flag
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: /go-cache/73/735aa16c44473681079e1f6b4a517de41fcac801aa803f5f84f6ebcb6436f3e6-d(_go_.o): cannot use dynamic imports with -d flag
```

Here is how I am compiling my project, within an `golang:1.17-alpine3.14` Docker container:

```
go build -ldflags "-d -X main.Something=$SOMETHING -X main.Another=$ANOTHER -linkmode external -extldflags -static" -tags netgo -o prog cmd/prog/*.go
```

Without the import, everything compiles fine. All I need to do to trigger this is the following:

```
import (
    archive/tar
    ...
)
...

func someFunc() {
    ...
    tarWriter := tar.NewWriter(file)
    defer tarWriter.Close()
}
```

Allowing this to be dynamically linked isn't something I can do, given requirements of the program. How can I get this to link statically?

Comment: What are your cgo dependencies? Why do you need `-d` in the first place?

Comment: I am not sure; it was there from before me. Removing it makes a successful build, and the binary is indeed statically linked. `go tool link` suggests that this is for `disable dynamic executable`, but in practice, what does this mean? And when might I want to use it? And why would it affect my build by adding `archive/tar`?

Comment: You probably should never use that directly, but not sure why the tar import specifically triggers the problem. If you want a static binary with cgo then using the external linker to statically link is sufficient. If you're not using cgo, then just disable it altogether because the default output of the Go compiler is a static binary.

Comment: That's a guess, but maybe `-d` indeed disable dynamic executable, but detects that the lib uses cgo imports, and makes an error because of that. However, your code maybe does not call the parts of the lib that uses them, so your final executable is fully static? If what I say is true, then you can't be sure that you have an executable that has only static link before it's compiled.

Comment: (maybe not related to this error, but you should never be building "files" like `cmd/prog/*.go`, you should build the package)

Comment: What is the `-d` flag doing in the first place? I can't find info on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `-ldflags` to avoid your program being dynamically linked, you can just disable it through the environment:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags "-X main.Something=$SOMETHING -X main.Another=$ANOTHER" -o prog $PACKAGE_PATH
```

E.g, this minimal (panicking) program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
)

func main() {
    tarWriter := tar.NewWriter(nil)
    defer tarWriter.Close()
}
```

compiles perfectly with:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0  go build -o prog .
```